# jQuery or Javascript-dynamically change linking (relative/site relative/absolute) depending on environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, path, external

To deploy a recent project I must use absolute pathing but for testing locally outside a server I'd like to use relative pathing for most of links to external scripts and images.

On another project I'd like to dynamically change relative pathing to site relative when the project is loaded from a server.

For both projects I'd ideally like to employ some reusuable method with javascript or jQuery that would automatically redefine these links depending on the testing environment.

So I know I need to set up some type of global path variable.

And then  in my HTML markup prepend the links with this variable.

But not sure how to implement.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: When you say "testing locally outside a server" do you mean using `file://` protocol?

Answer (score 1):

The best (and least annoying) way I use is mapping to local host.

Let's say you work on awebsite.com

- Keep all your links as absolute
- Map awebsite.com to 127.0.0.1 on your hosts file
- add awebsite.com to your virtual hosts file

It's done, now you access your testing environment as awebsite.com

When you want to browse the online website, just comment the line you added in hosts file.